# Why isn't my collision/contact working in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been working on contacts/collisions in my new game. I just coded this, and it's not working correctly. Here is my code:

Square Details:

```
    square.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/1.5)
    square.zPosition = 35
    square.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: square.size)
    square.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = squareGroup
    square.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = obstacleGroup
    square.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = obstacleGroup

    self.addChild(square)
```

Obstacle Details (Obstacle 1 and 2 are the same):

```
    obstacle1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle1.size)
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.mass = 10000
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = obstacleGroup
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = squareGroup
    obstacle1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = squareGroup
```

Here is my code for contacts between them and the category groups:

```
var squareGroup : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
var obstacleGroup : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1     

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
        }



        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 2{
            let newScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
           _ = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
            self.view?.presentScene(newScene)
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help me that'd be great. Ask questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
    }
```

At the else statement you have `firstBody = contact.bodyB` and `firstBody = contact.bodyA`

> I think you whanted to write `secondBody = contact.bodyA`

Also add double check for contact

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == 0x1 << 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 2) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == 0x1 << 2 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 1){

    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: @JoshSchlabach Can you be more specific ? What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Have you checked if didBeginContact is called at all ? Have you set contact delegate properly ?

Comment: The square will go through the obstacles and not do anything. Didbegincontact is called and so is contact delegate

Comment: @JoshSchlabach Have you added `@interface GameScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> {` and  `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;` to your scene?

Comment: @Darvydas yes I have added both and it still isn't working,

Comment: change `1` to `0x1 << 1` and `2` to  `0x1 << 2` then checking for contact

Comment: @Darvydas what's your skype? Can you help me walk through this?